# Very large image displaying progressive

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I'm trying to load in some decently large images into a web application. The largest of these images can be 2800x2800. I load them in, display, and everything works fine.

My problem is, once they are loaded using:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'myImageURL';
img.onload = function(){
  //display image
}
```

The large images display on the page progressively, from top to bottom as if they are being loaded.

I want to remove this visually, and only display them once fully loaded and rendered in the browser.

I cannot change the image sizes either, because this web app is intended for the user to scale the images, all the way up to 100% of original size, so I must load the full 2800x2800 and resize it small.

Does anyone know how I could hide the image until it's rendered? I can hide it until loaded, but that's basically what I'm doing and it's the progressive render display I want to remove.
Thanks

Comment: Pretty confident you're not going to get a solution to this, I'm afraid. You have no control over the browser visually painting the image onto the page.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple browsers? This sounds like a limitation of the browsers themselves and possibly even the computer depending on how the browser can use system resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onload` attribute on the `<img>` tag, something like this:

```
<img src="huge.jpg" style="display:none" onload="this.style.display='block'">
```

Substitute whatever you want for effects, but `onload` is your hook.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DfCUQ/1/ <sup>(note: update the `?nocache=X` in the demo for each time you load it)</sup>

Comment: The fiddle works great, but I don't see what my problem is still. I may need to look deep into how I'm loading my image, maybe there's some issue on my server with my resources :/

Comment: Great hack solution +1

Answer (score 0):

You could make the css visibility to 'hidden' and have some text (or loading spinner, etc) in the place of the image until the onload event gets called.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. The image does not get added to the page until `onload`, but once it's added, is displays progressively, being rendered in the browser.